# Encrypting a letter with RSA

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ascii, rsa, computer-science

I want to encrypt the letter 'Z' using ASCII (Z=90), using a key with two numbers: (17, 3233)

RSA:
90^17 mod3233 = 1668

I am wondering if there is any way of encrypting this letter into a char value.

Comment: You'll have to encode it into something that's computable numerically

Comment: No, not in any practical way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSA is not a stream cipher. The encrypted result always has the size (bits) of the modulus - in your case 3233.

The number 3233 requires 12 bits - however one byte/character provides only 8 bits. Hence you can't send pack the RSA encrypted text as one byte. You need at least 2 bytes.

If you can pack the integer in a char depends on your definition of a char:

## char = (printable) ASCII character

A printable ASCII character usually has 7 bit. You can't store 12 bits in 7 bit.

## char = byte

A standard character is equivalent of a byte and allows to store 8 bits. You can't store 12 bits in 8 bit.

## char = Java UTF-16 char

Considering that a Java `char` is an UTF-16 character you may be able to save the integer as one character, however storing binary data in a Java UTF-16 `char` is a very unclean and hackish solution. **I strongly recommend not implement this!** Binary data should not be saved in a character(Array) without proper conversion and encoding (e.g. base64 of hexadecimal encoding).

Answer (score -1):

All signed character values range from -128 to 127. All unsigned character values range from 0 to 255. So the only way would be to have those numbers inside that range.